# slidetoggle() makes divs moving on the side

Tags: jquery, css, html, slidetoggle

I've got a problem using .slideToggle(). I use this effect to open a rectangular div with a text description. I have 3 divs on two different row, contained in a main div with this style:

```
.main { float:left; width:100%; height:auto; max-width:978px;}
```

Every div has a wrapper with this style:

```
.wrapper { float:left; width:300px; height:100%;}
```

and a description container with this style:

```
.item_desc {float:left; width:270px; padding:10px; height:auto;}
```

The problem is that every description has a different kind of text (short and long) and this obviously affect the height of the container. When the first container (with the longest text) slide down, the divs below move on the right.

How can avoid it ? I would like the divs stay in the same position without moving because of the lenght of the text of the other container slided.

Is there a solution ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Can you share a fiddle of your work?

Comment: I can give you the website link: 
www.giaproma.it/team

Comment: Can anybody help me ?